# Wpf Textbox and label text access in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, label

I've got this basic WPF, I've done for practice, it's a sort of scorekeeping app, and I want to enter a number into a textbox, process it, and then put out the result in the label, but I cant figure out how to access them in the c# side. Here's the XAML:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Label Name="PlayerName" Style="{StaticResource PlayerName}"/>
    <Label Name="PlayerScore" Style="{StaticResource Score}"/>
    <ScrollViewer Height="380">
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBox Name="Number" MaxLength="3" Width="160" Margin="20" FontSize="30" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"></TextBox>
    <Button IsDefault="True" Style="{StaticResource Golden} " Click="Button_Click">Запиши резултат</Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource Golden}">Върни назад</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to enter a number in `Number` and after processing it, I want the current score to be displayed in `PlayerScore`

Edit: I haven't worked in the C# code on this one, and I would also appreciate it if anyone could tell me where I could do some more reading on this subject, so that I can do more advanced things, and be able to work with other controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by targeting the label at the textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Number" ... />

<Label x:Name="PlayerName" Target="{Binding ElementName=Number}" ... />
```

[MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label(v=vs.110).aspx)

This way you don't have to do anything in the C# to get the label to update.

To process the input you should ideally use something like MVVM (Model View ViewModel) and binding to get the value into C#, but as you are just learning you *could* just edit the code behind. IN the `TextBox_TextChanged` method you can get access to the text through the `Text` property:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    int score;
    if (TryParse(textBox.Text, out score))
    {
        // Value entered was an integer, process it
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I process the text from the textbox?

Comment: @Reaper9806 - ah, for that you need to either use MVVM (Model View VIewModel) or some such pattern or (as you are learning) edit the code behind.

Comment: you could always write an UpdatePlayerScore(int score) method and in it call PlayerScore.Content = score;

Comment: I just want to access the controls in the code behind, but even with x:Name, it doesn't work

Comment: Some of them I can, but even if I modify their content in the code, nothing happens